# Why isn't my jQuery working anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some simple jQuery on my website to expand information divs, it was all working fine the other day but I made some tweaks to my site (not the jQuery) and it's not working all of a sudden and I have no idea why...

This is one of the pages on my site

http://peterph.am/work/pierre-macarons

I've linked my jQuery externally with this:

```
<script src="../assets/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/libs/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/libs/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Start by trying to figure out the cause of your JS syntax error.

Comment: Show us the actual jQuery code that is not working, please. Also, what did you change, it could be that your selectors are wrong for example.

Comment: Anything in the JS console?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors if you open up the debug console in a browser? Any javascript errors will cause javascript to fail.

Comment: Try fixing this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input main.js:1

Comment: Try adding some code to this question, or it is likely that the question will be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
    $(function(){
         $.scrollUp({
         scrollImg: true,
         scrollDistance: 100,
         scrollSpeed: 800,
         easingType: 'linear'
    });
```

You're not closing the `$.scrollUp` call correctly. It should be:

```
$(function(){
    $.scrollUp({
        scrollImg: true,
        scrollDistance: 100,
        scrollSpeed: 800,
        easingType: 'linear'
    });
});
```

This highlights the importance of proper code indentation.

Comment: Ahh thank you, been staring at the problem too long!

Comment: No problem. You can guard against this type of error by using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, you've made changes to your `main.js` file and you've lost `});` at the end of it, which causes the js to throw an error per the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input | main.js
```

Simply add `});` to the end of your file, voila.

Comment: I'm perplexed as to why I've received a down vote. Explain.

Comment: Why -1? This is very likely to be the cause.

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch. Not sure why we both were downvoted though.

Comment: }); needs to be added not in the end of file

Comment: @JoaoPaulo It doesn't matter where it's added, as it's what's missing from the file.